# Check if there is a visible character inside an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I am curious whether there is an easy way in jquery (or javascript) to check whether there is a visible character inside a `div` or `td` element.

###### Example:

Let's say I have a table with a header and a row below as filters as follows:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        ....
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><input id="FirstNameFilter" /></th>
        <th>
            <select id="LastNameFilter">
                <option value="Smith">Smith</option>
                <option value="Doe">Doe</option>
                <option value="Nelson">Nelson</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        ....
    </tr>
</thead>
```

If the user wants to filter according to first name, he/she types something in the respective field, if he/she wants to filter according to last name, he/she selects from the drop down.
This then activates a javascript function which filters the rows of the table.

Now, is there a convenient way to get all those `<th>`'s where the user has typed or selected something?

`.is(':empty')` or checking for the visibility would not work obviously, and the only other option I can think of right now is to somehow check whether there is an element inside the `th` (because there could also be columns without filter), and if it's an `input` tag or `select` tag and then either query `.val()` or `.(':selected').val()` respectively.

So the question basically is, whether there's a way to check that with 1 function regardless of the type of element inside the `<th>` - I'm thinking of maybe there is a way to check if there is a visible character (on the DOM) somewhere inside the `<th>` (including it's sub elements even)?

Thanks

###### Edit

I'm basically looking for a selector to select:

- `th`'s which have an `input` element AND the `input` element is not empty
- `th`'s which have a `select` element AND the some `option` selected (who's value is not empty by the way)

What I don't want to get is:

- `th`'s which are empty
- `th`'s which have an `input` element but it is empty
- `th`'s which have a `select` element but no option selected or the selected option's value is null

Hope that's clearer

Comment: `const thsWithSomeText = [...document.querySelectorAll('th')].filter(th => th.textContent.trim() !=="")` perhaps?

Comment: This gets all the `th`s from the first header row (which is ok) and from the second header row only those `th`s which have a select element inside them, regardless of whether an option is selected or not and it does not select the `th`s with a value typed in the `input` tag by the user.

Comment: It is not clear enough what you want. Make a [mcve] and show expected output.

Comment: Is space "visible"? How about zero-width characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this?
I am not testing the tag does not have a value (for example a span or such) - that needs more coding

```js
const textAndValues = [...document.querySelectorAll('th')]
  .flatMap(th => [...th.childNodes]
    .map(node => node.nodeType === 1 ? node.value : node.textContent.trim()).filter(val => val)
  );

console.log(textAndValues)
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><input id="FirstNameFilter" /></th>
      <th>
        <select id="LastNameFilter">
          <option value="Smith">Smith</option>
          <option value="Doe">Smith</option>
          <option value="Nelson">Smith</option>
        </select>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```